# Xampp My SQL is not working

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed xampp and i changed port `80` to `1234` to start apache.Now apache is running fine on port `1234` and `1443`.
But MySql is not working.I tried changing port `3306` to `3307`.But it still pops up a window and ask me if I want to allow and give following message and frozen forever.

```
Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

When i start the xwamp it also gives following error;

```
MySQL Service detected with wrong path
10:15:22 AM  [mysql]    Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
10:15:22 AM  [mysql]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
10:15:22 AM  [mysql]    Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
10:15:22 AM  [mysql]    Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

to avoid this I have un installed MySQL. I don't have paths called

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini"
```

in my computer now. How can i fix this??

Comment: have you installed XAMPP & MySQL separately?

Comment: i have installed MySQL before the xampp installation.But i uninstalled MySQL after installing xampp.

Comment: Can you try re installing XAMPP?

Comment: i tried..But same result..

Comment: can you do a netstat -a and check whether the specified port for MySQL is already open?

Comment: I do.there is no other service is using port 3306 or 3307

Answer (score 0):

start -> run -> regedit.

It involves editing the registry, but service information can be found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services. **Find the mysql** service you want to redirect, locate the ImagePath subkey and change that value.

there you can set your default path :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this step :

Open a command prompt (Start > Run > cmd) run as administrator
Type the following:

Code: Select all
sc delete mysql